# What are the factors of the matrix M?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

A matrix is given by

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & bc\\ 
1 & b & ca\\ 
1 & c & ab
\end{bmatrix}$

What are the factors of this matrix M ?

---

**My Try** :-

Multiply $R1$ by $a$, $R2$ by $b$ and $R3$ by $c$. After that, take common $abc$.

$abc\begin{bmatrix}
a & a^2 & 1\\ 
b & b^2 & 1\\ 
c & c^2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

So, I think $abc$ will be one of the factors of this matrix $M$

---

Instead of this method, I tried by one more method applying row operations .

$R2\Rightarrow R2-R1$ and $R3\Rightarrow R3-R1$. This gives

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & bc\\ 
0 & b-a & c(a-b)\\ 
0 & c-b & a(b-c)
\end{bmatrix}

Hence, Determinant is $\left ( a-b \right )\left ( b-c \right )\left ( c-a \right )$, which says $(a-b)$ or $(b-c)$ or $(c-a)$ is the factor.

---

Hence, All the factors completely different by the two different methods. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by the "factors of the matrix"?

Comment: @Xoque55 If $det= (a−b)(b−c)(c−a)$, then $(a−b)$ and $(b−c)$ and $(c−a)$ will be the $3$ factors of $M$ .

Comment: I think you are talking about the determinant of the matrix? If so, note that when you do a row operation that involves multiplying by $a$ then you are multiplying the determinant by $a$; hence the spurious $abc$ in your first calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe that it took MSE almost seven years to find OP's mistakes in the row operations.

The determintant of the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & bc\\ 
1 & b & ca\\ 
1 & c & ab
\end{bmatrix}
is without doubt $(a-b)(c-a)(b-c)\,.$

With row operations,

$$\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & bc\\ 
0 & b-a & c(a-b)\\ 
0 & c-\color{red}a & \color{red}{b(a-c)}
\end{bmatrix}=b(b-a)(a-c)-c(c-a)(a-b)=(a-b)(c-a)(b-c)
$$
as it must.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$15i+30j+45k=5(3i+6j+9k)$

$15i+30j+45k=3(5i+10j+15k)$

What I meant to say is: if factors are different,then elements of matrix are also different,when multiplied,gives same matrix.